# Set TeeChart colorLine Visibility

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

Is there a way to programmatically hide a colorLine tool in TeeChart .NET?  There is no Visible property and setting Active to false still leaves it visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on the official forum, just try :

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;
  Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues(10);
    ColorEachPoint:=true;

    for i:=0 to Count-1 do
      ValueColor[i]:=OperaPalette[i];
  end;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TPointSeries) as TPointSeries do
  begin
    DataSource:=Chart1[0];
    ColorEachPoint:=true;

    for i:=0 to Count-1 do
      ValueColor[i]:=ModernPalette[i];
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise you can try to use a invisible color , instead of "Hidden".

Read these topics :

- http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?p=47991#p47991
- http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14199

Comment: That looks to be for Series Points not a colorLine "Tool".

Comment: i have just try to help you.